# VLC 3 interface looks "old"

Tags: gnome, vlc, appearance

VLC 3 looks "old"/"unstyled" after installation with snap.
Here is a screenshot[image]
As you can see the buttons are kind of unstyled.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What version is it ?

Comment: It is Snap problem, it does not support theming.

Comment: @chili555 is that OK? I mean that it looks like an app from early 00s.

Comment: @An0n the version is 3.0.0.

Comment: It is not OK. It is by Snap design. Have you installed it with `snap install vlc` or from GNOME/Ubuntu Software? Native looking apps are packaged as debs. It is [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1585332). What is the output of `snap list | grep vlc`?

Comment: @N0rbert just to make things clear: I'm not about vlc skins. Just for an instance, let's look at this pic https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/VLC-Player-About.jpg
As you can see, the buttons looks much pretty. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @N0rbert I've used `snap install vlc`.  Here is the output you requested:
`vlc      3.0.0                    158   videolan `

Answer (score 2):

## **To install the latest VLC :**

**Add repository :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vlc
```

**Delete previous versions VLC :**

```
sudo apt remove vlc vlc-nox
```

**Update and install the latest VLC version :**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install vlc
```

---

**To install from snap, follow this link :**
[How to install the vlc 3.0 snap in linux](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-install-the-vlc-3-0-snap-in-linux/)